# Handling multiple keys input at once with GLFW

Tags: c++, input, keyboard, glfw

I am trying to create basic camera movement with glfwSetKeyCallback function. The problem is it doesn't handle inputting multiple keys at once, like W and A should move it diagonally upper-left direction. Instead it acts like knowing only about last inputted key. So let's say I press A to move left, it goes left, then I press W to go diagonally upper-left, instead it 'forgets' about A being pressed and goes upward.

```
float cameraSpeed = 0.02f;
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && (action == GLFW_PRESS || action == GLFW_REPEAT))
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_W && (action == GLFW_PRESS || action == GLFW_REPEAT))
        Game::GetInstance()->cameraY += cameraSpeed;
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_A && (action == GLFW_PRESS || action == GLFW_REPEAT))
        Game::GetInstance()->cameraX -= cameraSpeed;
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_S && (action == GLFW_PRESS || action == GLFW_REPEAT))
        Game::GetInstance()->cameraY -= cameraSpeed;
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_D && (action == GLFW_PRESS || action == GLFW_REPEAT))
        Game::GetInstance()->cameraX += cameraSpeed;
```

The one solution that got into my mind was like create my own boolean tab of keyboard inputs and use GLFW function only to set them, like:

```
if (key == GLFW_KEY_A && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        // set 'A' to true;
if (key == GLFW_KEY_A && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        // set 'A' to false;
```

And then do what I want with it in totally separate function/class/whatever. It doesn't appear clean to me though. What is a good solution to the problem?

Comment: Do you have any specific difficulties with handling `GLFW_PRESS` and `GLFW_RELEASE`?

Comment: No, they work properly, until I have more than one key pressed. If I have two keys pressed(let's say again W and A) it should go up-left(keys are pressed all the time so it is GLFW_REPEAT), but instead only last key pressed is remembered.

Comment: Are you telling that you are not receiving `GLFW_RELEASE` for the first key?

Comment: I am not releasing first key at all, though when I do i get GLFW_RELEASE.
edit: Problem is that when I get GLFW_PRESS for second key, I don't receive GLFW_REPEAT for the first key anymore.

Comment: `GLFW_REPEAT` is received only for the last pressed and held key. There is nothing wrong with it. Actually there is no need to handle `GLFW_REPEAT` at all. You can handle `GLFW_PRESS` and `GLFW_RELEASE` and adjust camera position to the direction corresponding to currently pressed keys. Note that you should not wait for key events to update camera position like you do right now.

Comment: So the solution I suggested later is proper one? Because if I don't need to handle GLFW_REPEAT then I have no other way to know it's still pressed. Or do I?

Comment: Yes. Key is still pressed until `GLFW_RELEASE` arrives.

Answer (score 7):

I came across the same problem and decided to use callbacks to set an arrays worth of key states. `GLFW_REPEAT` is only sent for the last key pressed. My callbacks directly delegate to an `Input` class, but that's not relevant: they pass all the parameters along.

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow *win, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods){
    Input *input = (Input*)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(win);
    input->keys(win, key, scancode, action, mods);
}
```

The key press array defined inside Input:

```
bool pressed[KEYS]; // KEYS = 349 (last GLFW macro, GLFW_KEY_MENU = 348)
```

And the actual handling method, in which I also handle special keys that need the window pointer:

```
Input::keys(GLFWwindow *win, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods){
    if(key == GLFW_UNKNOWN) return; // Don't accept unknown keys
    if(action == GLFW_PRESS)
        pressed[key] = true;
    else if(action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        pressed[key] = false;

    switch(key){
    case GLFW_KEY_EXCAPE:
        if(action == GLFW_PRESS)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(win, true);
    }
}
```

Then I handle every key inside the main loop after every render operation with `Input::handle(void)`, used like `Input in(); in.handle()`:

```
void Input::handle(void){        // Things to do every frame
    for(int i = 0; i < KEYS; i++){
        if(!pressed[i]) continue;  // Skip if not pressed
        switch(i){
        case GLFW_KEY_SPACE:
            cam->ascend(1.0);    // Ascend with camera
        }
    }
}
```

I plan to include a time constant to deal with the issue of varying frame rates, but this is the gist of it.

Result: Camera moves smoothly in every direction even when pressing multiple keys.

Comment: Cheers for sharing your solution.  Rather than looping through th 350+ possible defined keys each frame others might prefer to just check the individual key and perform the associated action. e.g.  if (pressed[GLFW_KEY_SPACE]) cam->ascend(1.0);

Comment: @MichaelWhinfrey Oh that's a clever optimisation, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I implement my version of keyboard handle class :

```
enum EVENT{
    PRESS = 1,
    RELEASE = 2,
    REPEAT = 4,
    NONE = 8
};

static std::map<int, EVENT> event_map = {{GLFW_PRESS, PRESS}, {GLFW_RELEASE, RELEASE}};

class Input{
public:
    Input() {}
    Input(GLFWwindow *w) : window(w) {}
    void set_window(GLFWwindow *w) {window = w;};

void add_key_input(int key, std::function<void(int, float)> f, int events){
    // if (key == -1) {std::cout << "undefinet key : " << key << '\n'; return;}
    keys[key] = KEY(f, event_map[events]); 
}   

void process(float delta){
    for (auto& [key, info] : keys)  {
        int e = glfwGetKey(window, key);
        std::cout << key << " " << e << " " << info.action << " " << info.event << " ";

        if      (e == GLFW_RELEASE &&  info.action == NONE)                             info.action = NONE;
        else if (e == GLFW_RELEASE &&  (info.action == PRESS || info.action == REPEAT)) info.action = RELEASE;
        else if (e == GLFW_PRESS   &&  (info.action == PRESS || info.action == REPEAT)) info.action = REPEAT;
        else if (e == GLFW_PRESS   && (info.action == NONE || info.action == RELEASE))  info.action = PRESS;

        std::cout << info.action << "\n";     
        if (info.event & info.action) {
            info.callback(key, delta);
        }
    }
}

private:
    struct KEY{
        KEY():action(RELEASE) {}
        KEY(std::function<void(int, float)> f, EVENT e): callback(f), action(RELEASE) ,event(e) {}


    std::function<void(int, float)> callback;
    EVENT action;
    EVENT event;
};

GLFWwindow *window;
std::map<int, KEY> keys;
};
```

to use it. init :

```
key_input.set_window(window);
key_input.add_key_input(GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE, [this](int key, float delta){glfwSetWindowShouldClose(this->window, true);}, PRESS);
```

and in main loop :

```
glfwPollEvents();
key_input.process(delta_time); // in my case delta time is time in secs since last frame
```

You can replace std::function<void(int, float)> f, EVENT e> (function<> is sutusi me in my project) to std::any and pass any type of function, or try to use std::invoke and template<typename Args&...>.